# jquery validate - toggle fieldset (with nested required fields) based on conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Jquery gurus, I've been banging my head over this. I'm building a client-side form validation layer to a form rendering system that outputs markup like this (minimal example):

```
<form name="someName" action="someAction">
<label for="1">Product</label>
<select id="1" name="1">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="shoe">Shoe</option>
  <option value="hat">Hat</option>
  <option value="vest">Vest</option>
</select>

<!-- this fieldset would be enabled if select (id:1) IS NOT blank -->
<fieldset data-dep-values="" data-dep-operator="!=" data-dep-id="1" class="dependant">
    <label for="2">Brand</label>
    <input type="text" id="2" name="2" class="required">
</fieldset>

<!-- this fieldset would be enabled if select (id:1) IS blank -->
<fieldset data-dep-values="" data-dep-operator="=" data-dep-id="1" class="dependant">
    <label for="3">Other Product</label>
    <textarea id="3" name="3" class="required"></textarea>              
</fieldset>

<!-- this fieldset would be enabled if select (id:1) equals "shoe" OR "vest" -->
<fieldset data-dep-values="shoe|vest" data-dep-operator="=" data-dep-id="1" class="dependant">
    <label for="4">Material</label>
    <textarea id="4" name="4" class="required"></textarea>              
</fieldset>

<input type="submit">

</form>
```

Some things to note in the example:

- All fields that "could" be required are marked with the class "required"
- Fields and fieldsets can be flagged as "dependant," meaning they should be required "if" some condition in the form is met. In the example above, the data attributes on the fieldset elements denote the logic.

Here's my issue/question.

- Can the validate plugin add a listener to all fields, even if not required or format-based like data, int, email, etc. I need to detect changes on all fields, to test if there are any "dependents" for the field. Then I need to test the value against the dependency requirements.
- If a dependent field or group of fields is hidden (requirements not met), it will still have fields marked as required. Can Validate skip these fields, if the parent (dependant group) is not enabled (dependency not met)?

I'd assume it would run like this:

1. listen for changes on every input
2. when a field changes, search the form for `$('.dependant[data-dep-id="idOfChangedInput"]')` Then test the conditions. If true, show the dependent and include any child "required" fields in the Validation rules. Also hide and disable any previously enabled dependents (if conditions are no longer met)

It's a logic conundrum with mind-mangling consequences.

I have to believe there is a fairly basic way to set up this rule, but everything I try fails.

Any insight or suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: This sounds like a job for the observer pattern! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Set id to each fieldset with default property.
Suppose for first fieldset

```
<fieldset id="fs1" disabled="true"
```

for second fieldset

```
<fieldset id="fs2"
```

for third fieldset

```
<fieldset id="fs3" disabled="true"
```

You have to write a JS function which will be most likely.

```
function enableDisableFS() {
    var value = $("#1").val();
    if (value != "") {
        $("#fs1").removeProp("disabled");
        $("#fs2").prop("disabled", true);
        if (value == 'shoe' || value == 'vest') {
            $("#fs3").removeProp("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#fs3").prop("disabled", true);
        } 
    } else {
        $("#fs2").removeProp("disabled");
    }
}
```

And add onchange() attrubute to your select

```
<select id="1" name="1" onchange="enableDisableFS()">
```

Write another JS function if you want to validate form on submit.

```
function validate() {
    // if else validate do here depending on your conditions.
    if (valid) {
        document.forms[0].submit;
    } else {
        alert('Validation failed');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Your submit button

```
<input type="button" onclick="return validate()">
```